# Adjust height of div to content

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I have two divs, one on the left, and one on the right side of my page.
I have an iframe in the middle of my site, which content is loaded from a php file with mysql results in it.
I want the two divs on my page to get the TOTAL height of my page and set it as its own height so the borders continue all the way down. I also would like the iframe to adjust its height depending on the "results_table" which "myPhpFile" echoes out.

Here is my two divs code:

```
   <div class="bgr_left">
   <div class="bgr_right">
```

Here is the css:

```
  .bgr_right {
background-image: url(../Graphics/bgr_right.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-y;
background-position: right;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
width: 30px;
right: 0px;
background-color: #E7F5F0;
    }
```

AND

```
   .bgr_left {
background-image: url(../Graphics/bgr_left.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-y;
background-position: left;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 30px;
background-color: #E7F5F0;
    }
```

And here is the iframe inside a table:

```
    <table width="850px" height="1000px" border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
    <td width="845px" height="998px">
      <iframe style="border:none; width:100%; height:100%;" name="iframe001"  src="frame.html" id="iframe001"></iframe>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

And here is the form:

```
     <form id="nav_form_main" name="nav_form_main" action="bincgi/myPhp.php" target="iframe001" method="get">
```

And here is the part in the php file which creates a table from the mysql query:

```
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_result)){
```

My question: Is this way the best way to get two side borders on my page? AND, is there a way to set the iframe height to the content which is about to be loaded inside it from my "FORM"...

BACKGROUND HISTORY:
I have a form on my site, which targets the iframe, and the action on the form is a php file which returns a mysql query result inside a table. So this table is what ends up inside the iframe!

Comment: I never used `<iframe>` but setting an `height: 100%` on your divs should resolve the border problem.

Comment: It would be a big help if you could perhaps link to an example page. It would me it easier for me, and others to look into this for you.

Comment: sorry dont have it up online yet... but i know what u mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to resize an IFrame onload using Javascript can be done but is very cumbersome in my experience. Using Ajax to dynamically load the PHP results into your HTML structure would be easier and more reliable. If you load the PHP output into a DIV, that DIV's height can increase the page's height, thus increasing the other DIVs' height.

Answer (score 0):

You can access an iframe content height with JavaScript **only** if both the iframe and the JavaScript are **on the same domain**.

You can try inserting content with PHP like:

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://domain.net/iframe.php');

//
//Do something with the content here
//

echo($content);
```

But it's not clear solution if you can't modify the `iframe.php` to get only content you need. I think you'll end up with static iframe height.